# Questions & Answers in regards to some kind of Versioning

Tags: discussion

Is there some kind of established process / accepted practice when a version of something is / is not relevant?  You come across a question, but the answer is no longer valid because newer versions of a key element changed the code.  Often times, I see people simply start answering with the latest few versions.

"pre[this version] -do [this]. post[this version], do [this]."

Is there a proper way to indicate 'some version' is vital?

Answer (score 1):

Question about specific version should include that as tag or if none exist as text in the post. Additional clarification on accepted versions is welcome in the body of the post. Many tags have versions - i.e. most language tags ([c#-4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-4.0)) and major frameworks.

- If question is not tagged with specific version or does not explicitly mention version than use recent version for main answer and feel free to comment on alternatives for older versions.

  It is ok to add new answer if existing answers no longer apply due to version change. In case of very highly voted answers alternatively *consider* commenting on top existing answer about the problem - it is very hard to get new answer to the top thus effectively hiding new better answer.
- If question is tagged with particular version than answers with newer versions are generally not acceptable, answers using older version are ok as long as they apply to one requested.

---

Note: editing post by adding/removing version-specific tags must consider existing answers and preferably coordinated with or done by OP.